# receiving an empty buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I am trying to communicate with a TCP-Modbus but when I send the trace in the onAccept function it receives nothing as it has nothing, the send work as it works in the debugger, but when I debug in the receive it does not receive.

```
void CMisoc::OnAccept(int nErrorCode)
{
 unsigned char *ReceivedBuffer=new unsigned char[12];
 int len = this->Receive(ReceivedBuffer, 12);

 unsigned char *SendBuffer = new unsigned char[12];

 // Prepare answer with ModBus
 pDlg->MyModbus->ModBusReceived(ReceivedBuffer, SendBuffer, 1);

 // Answer
 pDlg->conected->Send(&SendBuffer[0], 12);

 delete[] SendBuffer;
 pDlg->conected->Close();

 Accept(*pDlg->conected);
 CSocket::OnAccept(nErrorCode);
}
```

Comment: You should override `OnReceive()` instead. The `OnAccept()` callback is used to accept the incoming connection request.

Comment: I have solved it, it was to create another Socket.

Comment: Also make sure you don't ignore the return value of `Receive()`.  It tells you how many bytes were actually read from the socket, which can be less than what you request.